# I want to get idle time of mouse, keyboard event

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, hook, mouse

I would like to display a pop-up window called 'Logged out' in c # if the mouse and keyboard did not raise an event for a certain amount of time when I  did nothing.

I found I have to use hooking. so I tried it. However I can get a value of mouse idle time but I couldn't get a value of keyboard idle time. The keyboard idle time is always 0.

Here is codes what i wrote.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Timer timer;
    private InputSource lastInput;
    private KeyboardInput keyboard;
    private MouseInput mouse;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        keyboard = new KeyboardInput();
        keyboard.KeyBoardKeyPressed += keyboard_KeyBoardKeyPressed;

        mouse = new MouseInput();
        mouse.MouseMoved += mouse_MouseMoved;

        lastInput = new InputSource();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetIdleTime() > 10000)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("test");
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private string FormatDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    private void keyboard_KeyBoardKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetIdleTime());
        if (GetIdleTime() > 10000)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("test");
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        label_keyboard.Text = FormatDateTime(lastInput.GetLastInputTime());
    }

    private void mouse_MouseMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetIdleTime());
        if (GetIdleTime() > 10000)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("mouse test");
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        label_mouse.Text = FormatDateTime(lastInput.GetLastInputTime());
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label_lastinput.Text = FormatDateTime(lastInput.GetLastInputTime());
        label_present.Text = FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now);
    }


}
```

and

```
class InputSource
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetLastError();

    public DateTime GetLastInputTime()
    {
        var lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;
        lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);

        GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo);

        //if (Environment.TickCount - lastInputInfo.dwTime > 10000)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("test");
        //}
        return DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-(Environment.TickCount - lastInputInfo.dwTime));
    }

    public static uint GetIdleTime()
    {
        var lastinput = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastinput.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastinput);

        GetLastInputInfo(ref lastinput);
        return ((uint)Environment.TickCount - lastinput.dwTime);
    }
    public static long GetTickCount()
    {
        return Environment.TickCount;
    }

    public static long GetLastInput()
    {
        var lastInPut = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInPut.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInPut);
        if (!GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInPut))
        {
            throw new Exception(GetLastError().ToString());
        }
        return lastInPut.dwTime;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwTime;
    }
}
```

If I want to get keyboard and mouse idle time correctly, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo

Comment: You don't use hooks in your sample, you just use GetLastInputInfo. Hooks to be used are **WH_MOUSE_LL** + **WH_KEYBOARD_LL**. and they work fine (just (re)tested on Windows 10 and I use them without problem since 90(s) for idle detecton or other things )